# How to show a day and date in timestamp data (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

i have a field with timestamp datatype in my database, this is the format when i added some record

example: this is chapter field of chapter table in database book

```
id       chapter     title     timepost
1        1           .....     2013-10-30 23:33:14
```

i want that format change in my web site like, `sunday,10 october 2013 - 23:33`

how to do that? thanks

**UPDATE:**Thank you for all your answer guys, all of your answer have worked correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mysql DATE_FORMAT function in your SELECT statement:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

For your request you would need:

```
DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%W,%e %M %Y - %H:%i')
```

Almost every language also has a date formating function, php use Date (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) but I believe this must be supplied a int.

Comment: Try `DATE_FORMAT(timepost,'%W,%e %M %Y - %H:%i') as mydate` in php `echo $myrow['mydate']`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this;

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W, %d %M %Y - %H:%i');
```

Out put:

```
'Sunday, 10 October 2009 - 22:23'
```

For more information you can see :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP `date()` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

I strongly recommend doing it on the client side. This way you can easily apply custom date and time formatting based in the users locale.

Im my opinion, formatting should not be done on the SQL server side. Moving string formatting from the SQL server to the web server takes the load from the SQL server and gives it more power to run queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_FORMAT function

```
select date_format(timepost,'%W, %M %e, %Y %h:%i %p') from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date('l,j F Y - H:i', $timepost);
```

*You could substitite the [format characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's date() function:

```
$date = date('l, d F Y - H:i', $date_from_mysql);
```

Use templates from PHP's Manual: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php