# get the data to datetime-local from php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a datatype "TIMESTAMP" in database. And I pass the value by using "datetime-local" attribute in html.

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="start_time" class="form-control" name="start_time"/>
```

this works fine and i can upload the date and time to database. But when i retrieve the data form database for editing, it doesn't work.

**PHP Code**

```
$query="SELECT * FROM hire WHERE hire_id='$id'";
$query_run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_run);
```

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $row['start_time']; ?>" />
```

The above php within the html shows nothing as a result. What is the fault here?

Comment: how are the column names from the `hire` table? What does `$id` contain when your query is built?

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($row);` to make sure you're getting back what you think you are?

Comment: yeap,, i remove some parts for easiness  .I think You can understand from the code without understanding database. @ArSeN

Comment: yes it works fine, but it cound not be printed within  `<input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $row['start_time']; ?>" />` @wogsland

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a day and date in timestamp data (PHP MYSQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766893/how-to-show-a-day-and-date-in-timestamp-data-php-mysql)

Comment: @Nishakar Well we can guess how the database looks like, but having a schema description could make sure that the mistake lies not therein. Thats why I was asking.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have the input type set to 'datetime-local'. You have to have the date set to the right format in order for it to show up in the input.

Change your start_time value to be in this format.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($row['start_time']));
```

Then in your input field echo out $date

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
```

Comment: It should not. When a browser does not understand the type, it defaults to "text" afaik.

Comment: @Nishakar Please accept as the answer if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you should get date from mysql then convert that string to date using `strtotime` function after that change the format of date and set it at `value` attribute of `input form control` haivng `type="datetime-local"`.

```
$string_to_date=$d=strtotime($date_fromdatabase);
$new_date=Date('Y-m-d\TH:i',$string_to_date);
```

set as a value attribute of input element in laravel 6

```
<input type="datetime-local"  class="form-control" value="{{ $new_date }}">
```